# CarrierWave::FormNotMultipart error when creating records using seed.rb file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave

I have a model that has a `image` column. I am using `CarrierWave` to upload images (I am following this [rails cast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/253-carrierwave-file-uploads) to do this.

Now, I want to create some default records using `seed.rb` file but I have failed to provided correct parh/url to the images.

So, I have images in List item `app/public/images/` folder and this is the code from the `seed.rb` file:

```
gems = {

    test1: {

        name: 'test1',
        description: 'test1',
        image: '/public/images/test1.png',
    },

    test2: {

        name: 'test2',
        description: 'test2',
        image: '/public/images/test2.png'
}

gems.each do |user, data|

  gem = DemoGem.new(data)

  unless DemoGem.where(name: gem.name).exists?
    gem.save!
  end
end
```

And I am getting the following error when I run `rake db:seed` command:

> CarrierWave::FormNotMultipart: You tried to assign a String or a
>   Pathname to an uploader, for security reasons, this is not allowed.

Could anyone tell how to provided correct `url` to the images?

Comment: @Pavan No I have not. Should I test with it as I am not using the form at all - I am inserting records using code :?

Comment: Try passing `image` as a file, using `File.open(path, 'rb')` if it's a local file

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Presuming that your `Gem` model has the `image` field as a Carrierwave uploader (that is, you've got `mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader` or similar in your `Gem` model), you can assign a ruby `File` object to your `image` attribute, not a string. Something like this:

```
gem = Demogem.new(data)
image_src = File.join(Rails.root, "/public/images/test2.png")
src_file = File.new(image_src)
gem.image = src_file
gem.save
```

---

In your overall code, you could either change your seed data (so your `image` property in your hash was set to `File.new(File.join(Rails.root, "/public/images/test1.jpg"))` or change the way you construct your new records so it doesn't use the `image` by default:

```
gems.each do |user, data|
    gem = DemoGem.new(data.reject { |k, v| k == "image" })
    gem.image = new File(File.join(Rails.root, data["image"]))

    unless DemoGem.where(name: gem.name).exists?
        gem.save!
    end
end
```

The [CarrierWave wiki has some documentation on this](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/How-to:-%22Upload%22-from-a-local-file), but it's not very extensive.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I do on my case:

```
["Sublime Text 3", "Internet Explorer"].each do |title|
  unless Post.exists?(title: title)
    post = Post.create!(title: title,
                        subtitle: "Subtitle of the #{title}",
                        content: "A sample post of the content about #{title}",
                        author: User.first)
    post.attachments_attributes = [file: Rails.root.join("spec/fixtures/photo.jpg").open]
    post.save!
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

A smart way to put the content in seed file like this

```
Rails.root.join("#{Rails.root}/app/assets/images/image_a.jpg")
```